# Vector: fill and export

Tags: photoshop

I have an icon in the form of a vector (belonging to one of the [Glyphish](http://www.glyphish.com/) sets) and I would like an icon a little larger than the sizes they provide by default.

This is what I am looking at in Photoshop at the moment:
[image]

That vector does not seem to be **there** though. I.e. I can see it, but I cannot fill it because when I deselect it, it seems to disappear (if you look in the layer view, you can see that nothing is actually visible).

So I wondered how I can fill it with a colour and export it as a PNG if possible? Many thanks.

Comment: If it is a vector I suggest you open it with Illustrator...

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I do not have Illustrator available. I could download a trial - what method would I need to follow to complete the task however?

Comment: ok then you can try importing it (import command), then you add a layer effect (layer panel on the bottom right of your screenshot), their should be a color lens ( try also other effects) that will add color to your layer_

Comment: what's the extension of the file you're trying to modify? @mrtux generally photoshop and illustrator are part of the same suite, so I think it has to be considered as a solution to a question

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot this looks like a Path, not a Shape layer. When pasting to Photoshop, use Paste as "shape layer" instead of "Path" (on the "Paste" dialog box that opens when you try to paste a vector shape.

Or: if you open the PSD file and it is already like that, then go to the "Paths" panel and click the icon "Load path as selection", from where you can fill it with color as a normal pixel selection.

Comment: My apologies - my Photoshop terminology is not up to scratch :). Thanks for the suggestion - trying it now and I'll let you know!

Comment: Hmm seems like Paste is the only option available to me - no "Paste Special"

Comment: do you see it in the "Paths" panel?